# Iterating through files in a folder in D

Tags: d

In D programming, how can I iterate through all files in a folder?
Is there a D counterpart to [python's glob.iglob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)?

Comment: To add on the answers: There are the following SpanMode's:
shallow (Which only spans one directory.)
depth (Which spans all sub directories before the actual directory.)
breadth (Which spans all sub directories after the actual directory.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_file.html#dirEntries

So like

```
import std.file;
foreach(string filename; dirEntries("folder_name", "*.txt", SpanMode.shallow) {
     // do something with filename
}
```

See the docs for more info. The second string, the *.txt filter, is optional, if you leave it out, you see all files.

The SpanMode can be shallow to skip going into subfolders or something like SpanMode.depth to descend into them.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [`std.file.dirEntries`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_file.html#.dirEntries). It will allow you to iterate over all of the files in a directory either shallowly (so it doesn't iterate any subdirectories), with breadth-first search, or with depth-first search. And you can tell it whether you want it to follow symlinks or not. It also supports wildcard strings using [`std.path.globMatch`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_path.html#.globMatch). A basic example would be something like

```
foreach(DirEntry de; dirEntries(myDirectory, SpanMode.shallow))
{
    ...
}
```

However, because `dirEntries` returns a range of `DirEntry`s, it can be used in the various range-based functions in Phobos and not just with `foreach`.